# How to disable ons-icon in Onsen-ui

Tags: onsen-ui

Is there any option to disable ons-icon.

Tried below options

```
1. <ons-icon disabled="disabled" onclick="testAlert()" icon="ion-navicon" size="40px"></ons-icon>
2. <ons-icon ng-disabled="true" onclick="testAlert()" icon="ion-navicon" size="40px"></ons-icon>

Javascript:
function testAlert()
{
  alert('Called');
}
```

Onclick, the alert should not be popped

Expected Result: The alert should not be popped, because the icon is disabled.

Note:
 1. Tried Option 1 for ons=button and is working fine

Comment: You can try giving it the CSS rule `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: Thanks Andreas, it is working fine......